# What is the best way to store a foreign key reference to multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables, upvotes, comments, and posts. Since both comments and posts can be upvoted here is what I'm currently using:

```
CREATE TABLE upvotes(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
  comment_id INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id),
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)

CREATE TABLE comments(
      id PRIMARY KEY,
      body TEXT,
      user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
      time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
    )

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  body TEXT,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

Is there some way to represent both posts and comments together in some sort of view or table where I can more elegantly reference it from upvotes e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE upvotes(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  item_id INTEGER REFERENCES items(id), /*this could be a post or a comment*/
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

Is there a way to create a table or a view items that would make this possible? Is there a better way to group the set of items that can be upvoted such that they all have their own unique primary key id (the reason I am stuck here is because a post and a comment might have the same primary key). Sorry if this is an obvious question, I was not sure how to phrase this when I was searching so it could be a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly what your question is. Can you please provide the schemas of the different tables so I can see what the relationships are among them?

Comment: Basically, I would like to group posts and comments together in a way that I could have a unique id that could identify either a post or a comment. Right now my problem is that posts and comments have their own separate primary keys, so if I have an id I don't know if it's a post or a comment. I edited my original post to include the schemas for posts and comments.

Comment: Could you have a single table, say, 'UserInput' that has a single primary key and then a secondary identifier column that codes the row entry as either a post or a comment? The other columns in this table would be the union of the columns in the two tables you have above. It's not the most efficient solution but it solves your problem.

Comment: That was my instinct, I was hoping someone would have a better way but I might just end up going with that. Thanks!

Comment: What is `users`? #bagger

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
      id PRIMARY KEY,
      body TEXT,
      user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
      time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
    )

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  body TEXT,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

instead use:

```
CREATE TABLE user_input(
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  inputType smallint,
  title TEXT,
  body TEXT,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

And add indices for id, inputType.